# how to solve java.lang.NullPointerException for array assignment

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, assign

I am trying to assign a variable from SQL result to array element but it keeps showing me java.lang.NullPointerException. I tried to declare the array above but it seems not working. The exception doesn't show the line of the error but I write print statements to figure out the exception place then I found out that when I print the value of the `activity[i]` it equals `null`.

Here is the code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.EventQueue;    
public class ACTIVITY {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement stm;
    private String sql;
    private ResultSet rs;

    private static int c_id=-1;
    private static int s_id=-1;
    private int a_id=-1;
    private String activity[]=new String[5];
    private int activityID[] =new int[5];

    public static JFrame frame;

     /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ACTIVITY window = new ACTIVITY();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ACTIVITY() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con= 
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1","****" , "********");
            stm= con.createStatement();
            sql="Select * from activity where sid="+s_id;
            rs=rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);
            String name=" ";int i=0;
            while(rs.next()){
                name=rs.getString("a_name");
                a_id=rs.getInt("a_id");
                activity[i]=name;//after this assignment it always equal null
                activityID[i]=a_id;
                i++;
            }

//the rest of the code

            con.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget to call `initialize()`? Are you sure there are rows matching that query?

Comment: Did you instantiate your activity array before the while loop? It looks like you snippeted your code... If you can edit this question and include the main method with all of the associated calls, plus any initialization of the variables you utilized in the while loop it'll be easier to answer accurately.

Comment: @Savior I call `initialize()` and there are matching rows. When I print out `name` it has a value, but when I print out `activity[i]` it equals `null`.

Comment: @ZachRieck I edited the code as you want.

Comment: You'll have to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd suggest using ArrayList instead of an array for this, but that's just personal preference. Here's an article on that https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp

As far as the issue as you have it, the problem is you have a declared a private string array and are trying to assign values to it in another method. The array is populating with default values of null since it's a String array. The reason you're getting the exception is because it's returning this default value rather than your assigned value.

You can still use a private array, but you'll want to declare it as static and use a static method to add a value to it. That way, when you add the value to it, it'll be returnable the way you expect. This is a much simpler example, but shows how to achieve this:

```
public class Test {

private static String activity[] = new String[5];

public void addValue() {
    activity[0] = "Yo";
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.addValue();
    System.out.println(activity[0]);
}
}
```

As for your specific code, I would suggest declaring both activity[] and activityID[] as static arrays. Then, you will need to create an object in your main method to call your value. Your changes would look like this:

```
private static String activity[] = new String[5];
private int activityID[] =new int[5];
```

Then in your main method, add:

```
window.initialize(); //where window is your class object you declared
```

That will get you the result you want. I'd also suggest renaming your method you called the same thing as your class.